# Impossible to create a file in the storage root directory?

Tags: java, android

I have a simple app am trying to finish:
//listing all of the SD Cards file names in a txt file.

And I've tried so many ways of at least creating the file in the root storage directory but with no luck ( not in the apps private files using "getFilesDir()" )  and one of those ways are shown in the code sample.
And yes i used the proper permissions.

Any help would be so much appreciated.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(path, "Something.txt");
    file.mkdirs();

    String[] array = file.list();

    try {

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        osw.write(String.valueOf(array));
        osw.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How does it fail? For example, any stack trace printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging and playing around a bit,

it turns out that i forgot to to call "fos.close()" and not just "osw.close()"

as well calling "file.createNewFile()" was mandatory , "mkdirs()" isn't working for some reason.

but thanks to everyone, all of your participation and effort were appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writting to external storage add this permisions to your manifest file:

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
</manifest>
```

acording to this [Article.][1]

Comment: I forgot to mention the permissions were added as well.

Comment: Where do you want to write file, Internal or External storage?

Comment: External Storage, the SD card itself so the user can access the file from any simple file manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call osw.close(); for the file to be created.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for the note, i also forgot about it.. but still no luck :(